# What are some ways to keep blood pressure low during muscle-strengthening excercises?

Tags: exercise

My hearing is sensitive to high blood pressure, so I am interested in the blood pressure of the head.
May it be the type of excercise, circumstances or anything, I am interested.

Comment: In my personal experience, my hearing is occasionally _transiently_ reduced in the few minutes after a heavy set of squats.  It does not persist.

Comment: Have you ever heard tinnitus while in that state?

Comment: Yes, I have had/heard tinnitus while in that state -- again, _transiently_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing certain lifts is going to cause a (significant) spike in blood pressure, so I doubt it can be avoided. In fact, doing so would put you at risk, since the elevated blood pressure is a result of taking a deep breath and increasing the intra-abdominal pressure using the valsalva maneuver. That should be done to provide the correct abdominal bracing and rigidity of the upper body during lifts such as squats, deadlifts and overhead presses. Even on bench presses getting some good pressure in your abdominal cavity will help stability. Failure to do so can result in poor form in the best case (folding over on squats, rounded back on deadlifts...) and increasing your risk for a back injury in the worst case.

So doing big compound lifts requiring a rigid trunk is going to give you requirements that run opposite of keeping blood pressure neutral. Your best bet would be to choose exercises that cause minimal elevation of the pressure. Isolation exercises are good candidates for this, since they will have less muscles involved at any particular moment (meaning less blood pressure variations) and usually don't require the stability and rigidity of your whole body (so no valsalva required). It is suboptimal since you get the best return on your investment of time with the compound lifts, but given your constraints it might be the only way.

When you say your hearing is sensitive to high blood pressure, is it actually a problem that would get progressively worse and cause damage? Or is it just a temporary inconvenience? If it's the latter, depending on your tolerance for it you may be capable of simply trying to deal with it. I can't think of some other solution short of putting a pressure cuff around your neck to block blood flow, but maintaining consciousness should probably be highest on your priority list.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question which often comes up and should be directed to a medical doctor. The doctors with whom I interact give this advice-

1) Do NOT hold your breath while exercising; do not restrain your breath at all

2) Do NOT grip unnecessarily- i.e. during leg machine exercises. Gripping hard directly raises your blood pressure.

3) As much as practically possible *relax* the unused muscles of your body.

These are learned skills. Most people will grip a machine HARD, contort their face, hold their breath and otherwise strain even untargeted muscles when they are working hard. All of these things raise blood pressure.